# Bootstrap : Footer with image full div height

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have a page with an image that takes the full height of the browser window, a column with text on the right side and a footer.

With full screen size the footer sticks at the bottom but it doesn't any more when the screen size is reduced as shown on the picture below.

[image]

How could I make the footer stick at the bottom in this configuration, and as a bonus, maybe how could the footer not hide a part of the text on the right side column when using large screens?

JSFiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/bb61c412/273/

And corresponding code:

```css
.navbar {
  background-color: #FF0000;
  opacity:0.7;
  border: 0 !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none !important; 
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 50px;  
}

.fill { 
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#picture{ 
    height: 100%;  
    background-image: url("http://uploads2.wikiart.org/images/paul-gauguin/road-in-tahiti-1891.jpg"); 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
    background-position: bottom center;
}

#right-column{
  overflow-y : scroll;
  background-color:#E8E8E8 ;
  height: 100%;
}

#footer{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #FF0000;
    opacity:0.7;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://bootswatch.com/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />


<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top ">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">         
        </div>
     </div>
</div>

<div class="container fill">

<div class="col-sm-8" id="picture"></div> 

<div class="col-sm-4" id="right-column">
  <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam molestie augue ac aliquet gravida. Vestibulum molestie euismod posuere. Nam posuere nulla sed nisl cursus fermentum. Aenean lobortis libero sodales purus fringilla placerat. Duis commodo ornare venenatis. Cras euismod arcu vel vehicula elementum. Vivamus vestibulum a lorem vitae posuere. Pellentesque faucibus vehicula auctor. In aliquam viverra fermentum. Aliquam dapibus nibh et magna laoreet, dignissim feugiat turpis eleifend. Aliquam porta fringilla elementum. Integer ut pellentesque ipsum. Nunc et purus vitae dui placerat pellentesque. Phasellus egestas diam ut eleifend lobortis. Nulla ultricies pulvinar ante et elementum.



 <p>
</div> 
</div>


<footer id="footer"></footer> 


<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find the solution in the below link 
https://jsfiddle.net/wwut6apr/1/ `position:fixed`
You have to add **position: fixed** instead of **absolute**  for the footer.

For you to read the bottom text on the right side bar, add a **padding bottom** of **30px** to your right-column.

Thanks

Comment: Thx for your help! the padding bottom doesent work because it is in competition with the 100% height of the div. One way would be to use : height: calc(100vh - 80px); for the #right-column. But is that a clean way to do it?  here is an example https://jsfiddle.net/wwut6apr/13/

Comment: Well finally, more simple : body:padding-bottom:30px   https://jsfiddle.net/wwut6apr/16/

Answer (score 0):

You need to **wrap** the content above your `footer`, and add a push `div` to make the footer stick to bottom.

[Modified fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bb61c412/274/)

It is explained here : http://ryanfait.com/resources/footer-stick-to-bottom-of-page/